# Updating multiple objects with select_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, associations

I've got a User model, a Team model, and a CoachingRole model.  The CoachingRoles model serves to associate Users and Teams because a one to many association already exists between Users and Teams.  The respective associations are set up like this:

User:

```
has_many :coaching_roles
has_many :teams_coaching, :through => :coaching_roles, :source => :team
```

Team:

```
has_many :coaching_roles
has_many :coaches, :through => :coaching_roles, :source => :user
```

CoachingRole

```
belongs_to :team
belongs_to :user
```

I have a form to edit a User and part of it is to add Teams to its CoachingRoles.  Here's the select_tag that I have so far:

`= select_tag "user[coaching_role_ids]", options_for_select(@teams.map {|t| [t.name, t.id]})`

That particular line will add a Team id to the User's `coaching_role_ids`, but will clearly not add the inverse.  Eventually I'd like to add `:multiple => true` to that and allow the selection of multiple Teams to be added to a User's CoachingRoles.  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this in my implementation.

Assuming that Team has attribute for name and a method selected_team_ids which returns an array of team ids selected for that user.

```
select_tag ("user[coaching_role_ids][]"), options_from_collection_for_select(Team.all, :id, :name, @user.coaching_role_ids), :multiple => true
```

Hopefully it helps!

EDIT: I edited the solution above based on @nilmethod's own discovery.
My original solution was:

```
select_tag ("user[teams][]"), options_from_collection_for_select(Team.all, :id, :name, @user.team_ids), :multiple => true
```

I'm guessing my tables were setup a little bit differently then. Thanks!

Comment: Close, but accepting the answer as it was nearly spot on.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction, though.  Here's what worked: ```select_tag ("user[coaching_role_ids][]"), options_from_collection_for_select(Team.all, :id, :name, @user.coaching_role_ids), :multiple => true ```

Comment: Great that it helps. My original solution worked for me. Let me double check and see how my tables and models are set up to see if I missed anything.